# How can I list an array out in the console like this? 1. ${array[0]} \n ${array[1]} but instead of me entering it manually I can do it automatic?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, console.log

Basically, I am trying to list an array in the console like this, I will give an example.

config.json

```
{
Names: [
"Stewart",
"Bob",
"Kevin"
]
}
```

And then the console would print out once called in a JS file

1. Stewart
2. Bob
3. Kevin

And also if I were to add more code to the array it would keep on listing numbers like that.

I haven't tried anything yet, I am mostly new to this.

Comment: do it inside a loop

Comment: @ChrisG elaborate, give me an example. i didnt clarify but by new i mean very new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) of your Names array inside your object like this

```js
const myObj = {
  Names: [
    "Stewart",
    "Bob",
    "Kevin"
  ]
}

const result = myObj.Names.forEach((ele, index) => { 
  let i= index+1;
  console.log(i + ' - ' + ele); 
})
```

or the alternative for loop

```js
const myObj = {
  Names: [
    "Stewart",
    "Bob",
    "Kevin"
  ]
}

for (let i = 0; i < myObj.Names.length; i++) {
     let index= i+1;
     console.log(index + ' - ' + myObj.Names[i]);;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do this

```
`const config = {
   Names: [
  "Stewart",
      "Bob",
     "Kevin"
     ]
 };

for (let i = 0; i < config.Names.length; i++) {
     console.log(`${i+1}. ${config.Names[i]}`);
 }`
```

Answer (score 0):

To list the contents of an array in JS, you can use a loop.
There are few concepts here worth looking into to understand how the example loop works:

1. Valid json: you need quotations around the "Names" key in your config.json file
2. The use of require() module to access the json file data
3. The For loop: this example loops over the length of the array using the index variable as a iterator and console.log()'s value of the names array at that index
4. What is being logged: The example has a string literal to match the numbered list example in your prompt but you can also simply log the value with `console.log(names[index])`

```
const data = require('./config.json');
let names = data.Names
for (let index = 0; index < names.length; index++) {
    console.log(`${index + 1}. ${names[index]}`)
}
```